# Codeigniter: Extending controller to create global methods

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, model-view-controller

I installed the [Bed Edmund's Ion Auth login script](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) and would like to make the functions global throughout my application.

I installed the code and it works great, but I'm having issues extending it. The ion Auth controller extends CI_Controller, so then in all my other controllers I extend Auth.

```
//Ion Auth Controller Class
class Auth extends CI_Controller {
```

and in a separate page:

```
//Home Page Controller Class, where I will be placing the login form
require_once("auth.php");
class Home extends Auth {
```

By doing this, I get the following PHP error:

```
Message: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated
```

I read in the CodeIgniter docs that extended classes must now begin with MY_, so I tried that as well with no luck.

What am I doing wrong? Is my logic all wrong?

Comment: should be able to load as library. I also use MY_Controller and have no problems by following docs

Answer (score 0):

Do a CTRL-F for `=&` inside the Auth class source code (the one you installed) and replace every instance by `=`.

`$foo =& new Bar();`
is a deprecated syntax that was used in PHP4 but no longer in PHP5.

Comment: Unfortunately a search for =& didn't return anything in the Auth controller.

Comment: Not inside the controller; inside the source code of the plugin. @steeped